# I want to print names of employees who have both work number and mobile number.below is my json body

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, for-loop

I want to print firstname of employees who have both work number and mobile number. Below is my json body. I am facing difficulty in getting inside `phoneNumbers` attribute. My final output should be: "Adhi as Adhi has both work and mobile numbers".

I am not able to iterate the inner dictionary of phoneNumbers attribute.Can you please help me on this.
This is my python code

```
 for i in Data['users']:
        for j in i['phoneNumbers']:
          for i in range(len(j)):
              if j['type']=="work" and j['type']=="mobile":
                  print("Firstname",i['firstName'])
```

Comment: It would be better if you add the dictionary in your question as text instead of adding it as a screenshot.

Comment: Can you post your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes. I have posted it

Comment: Don't post images of text.  Don't expect answerers to manually retype your input file to test it.  We can't cut-n-paste text in images.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience.It won't be repeated.

Comment: I've removed the data because 1) It looked a lot like real people's info and 2) It was an image. Feel free to edit some dummy data back into the question (as text, not an image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the users and check if the work and mobile number are present:

```py
for user in Data['users']:
    has_mobile_number = False
    has_work_number = False

    for phonenumber in user['phoneNumbers']:
        if phonenumber['type'] == 'work':
            has_work_number = True
        if phonenumber['type'] == 'mobile':
            has_mobile_number = True

    if has_work_number and has_mobile_number:
        print('Firstname', user['firstName'])
```

Also, I recommend not using `i` and `j` when not talking about indexes. In you code, `i` is a `dict` representing a user and `j` is a `dict` representing a phone. I replaced them with `user` and `phonenumber` for more clarity in the code above.